# Laravel checkbox data only saves true or false to the DB

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

My Ajax call passes checkbox value to the controller without problems. I have passed as true or false and tried as 1 or 0 values. But when I try to save the data to DB I am only able to save true/1. If I modify the code I can save false/0.

EXAMPLE: if I do click the checkbox and save true value for example. That is saved to DB, but whenever I unclick the checkbox the false value is not saved to DB.

Hope someone can help me to understand what is the problem. I try to include as much of my code as possible.

```js
function privacyFunction(id) {
    var checkBox = id;
    var checkboxName =  id.name;
    var checkboxData =  id.checked; //? 1 : 0
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+'/settings/privacy/save',
        type: "POST",
        data: {'checkboxName':checkboxName, checkboxData:'checkboxData'},
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(checkboxName, checkboxData);
        },
    });    
}
```

```css
public function save(Request $request){

        $user = Auth::user();

        $checkboxName = $request->checkboxName;
        $checkboxData = $request->checkboxData;
        
        if($checkboxData == true){
            $data = 1;
        } else {
            $data = 0;
        }

        if($checkboxName === 'private_profile'){
            $update = DB::table('users')
                ->where('user', $user->id)
                ->update([$checkboxName => $data]);
        }
        
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="private_profile" id="private_profile" value="1" @if($details['private_profile'] == 1) {{ 'checked' }} @endif onclick="privacyFunction(this);">
```

Comment: Share the data by doing ```dd($checkboxData)```

Comment: Can you check in developer tool -->network  whether the data is sending in correct format

Comment: Hi I the network payload is sending as:
checkboxName: private_profile
checkboxData: checkboxData
Not a value. Do you know how I can pass the value instead? thank you!

Comment: ```data: {'checkboxName':checkboxName, 'checkboxData':checkboxData},```
try by replacing this line

Comment: Thank you so much! it works... I changed {'checkboxName':checkboxName, 'checkboxData':checkboxData} to {'checkboxName':checkboxName, checkboxData:checkboxCheck? '1' : '0'}